# Intercept Global Function

Tags: lua

Is it possible to intercept a global function call, and run another function when the global is called.

```
local test = global()
function test()
print("Hello World")
end
```

I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

Edit

My original question was phrased poorly I ended up coming up with this solution.  The functions I'm trying to change are inside of a table so I just make a copy of the table, overwrite the function and then copy the backup table over the original to restore the function.

```
copy = {}
i,v = next(globaltable, nil)
while i do
        copy[i] = v
        i,v = next(globaltable,i)
        end

function globaltable:function()
do some stuff
globaltable = copy
end
```

Comment: What doesn't work? If you call `test` your *new* test function will be called. What's your expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to actually call `test` when calling `global()`, assign `test` to `global`:

```
local old_global = global
global = test
```

This makes `global` to refer to the function object of `test`.